# How to upload a .txt file as a .rtf file in C#?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

How can I load a pre-existing .txt file as a .rtf file in my C# code if 
I want to display it on a richTextBox? I am running Visual Studios Windows 
Application.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("filename.txt");
MyRichTextBox.Rtf = text; // oops, flying blind here
```

Comment: As opposed to `MyRichTextBox.Rtf = text;`

Comment: @joel you know you could have fixed my bug and saved me some embarassment but nOOOOOoooo....

Answer (score 4):

You might also try

```
MyRichTextBox.LoadFile("filename.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

---

edit: corrected to add `RichTextBoxStreamType` parameter.

Comment: I don't think that will work since richTextBox only 
supports .rtf, according to the yellow box description in
Visual Studios.

Comment: I stand corrected.  It should be:
MyRichTextBox.LoadFile("filename.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

Comment: Instead of giving a correction in a comment, you should edit your own answer and put it there.

Comment: Thanks, Oliver.

As you can tell, I'm new around here (at least in a posting capacity.)  I'm still trying to figure out how Joel embedded code markup in a comment.  :-/

Answer (score 0):

If the text file contains plain text and not text in rtf format, you can use:

```
MyRichTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText("filename.txt");
```